# Date Picker Max value can't be selected after moving to previous date in C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, date, datepicker, xamarin.android

I have this code to get a value of min date and max date I selected in datepicker. But right now, I am having a problem with max date. When I clicked the datepicker, the default value is TODAY. but when i switched it with previous date then go back to today's date, I can't select the date for today again. What's happening?

```
        dialog.DatePicker.MinDate = (long)SpecificTransDate.ToUniversalTime()
            .Subtract(DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(1969)).TotalMilliseconds;
        dialog.DatePicker.MaxDate = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: It works fine for me, can you share a simple demo about your code ?

Comment: how can I share? have you tried my code? have you tried picking the mindate then goback to today which is the maxdate?

Comment: Github, I create a DialogFragment to use these methods and it works fine, so I want use your code to reproduce this problem.